# angular js - ng-hide/ng-show API not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here i trying to implement application in angular js. I have an minimize/maximize button for all child element and seprate minimize/maximize button to inside child element.
But when i click `toggle` minimize its minimize all all child element.
Problem is when i click `toggleonce` it also minimize all child element.

```
var dashboard = angular.module("dashboard",['ui.bootstrap']);
dashboard.controller('dash-control', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.isHidden = false;
    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
    };
    $scope.toggleonce= function()
    {   
       if( this.isHidden === true)
           this.isHidden = false;
       else
           this.isHidden = true;
    };
}]);
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="contentpanel" ng-app="dashboard" ng-controller="dash-control as ctrl">
 <button class="btn btn-white" type="button" ng-click="toggle()">
 <i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i>
 </button>

<div>
<a href="" class="tooltips" ng-click="toggleonce()" title="Minimize Panel">
<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
</a>
<div class="row tinychart" ng-show="isHidden">Contenr Heading 1</div>
<div class="row tinychart" ng-hide="isHidden">Content Description 1</div>
</div>

<div>
<a href="" class="tooltips" ng-click="toggleonce()" title="Minimize Panel">
<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
</a>
<div class="row tinychart" ng-show="isHidden">Contenr Heading 2</div>
<div class="row tinychart" ng-hide="isHidden">Content Description 1</div>
</div>
......
.....
.....
</div>
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine. You have just one boolean variable attached to all div tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable $scope.isHidden is a controller level variable and by clicking toggleonce() you are changing the variable to true through out the page(since both the 'minimize panels' are in the scope of the controller. Thereby any ng-hide for isHidden will be hidden and thereby it is causing the global 'minimise'. 
You have two options:

1) use separate variables for each Minimize panel and toggle the values of that variable when you click on the corresponding function. Also write the Panel level 'ng-hide's for its own variable.

2) write a isolated scope directive for all Minizable panels. And isolate its scope from the Controller. Now write a toggleonce function in the directive which changes the value of the Hidden variable within the directive's scope. You must use the following syntax while writing the directive:

```
 .directive('minimizePanel', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
  };
```

You can watch [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope) video for more inputs.

Comment: can you explain how to create isolate directive?

Comment: Make sure that you give 'scope:true' for the directive so that the scope is inherited from the controller but is isolated from it. In other words, all the variables in the controller's scope are present in the child(directive's) scope. But the changes made to them in the directive are not propagated back to the Controller. This ensures that each time you call the directive, a separate scope object is created for that instance of the directive. You can go through egghead video shared above for more detailed info. Suggest you to watch all of their angular videos.

Comment: Sure. No problem. Let me know how things go.